# Python version management and venv - how to make the env folder available inside a project folder using pyenv?

Tags: github, virtualenv, python-venv, pyenv

I have a project that I want to work in a different Python version from my OS.
In this example my OS is Ubuntu 22 - Python 3.10.4 and I want to create a project using Python 3.8.4.

When we want to work with a new python environment with different libraries from our OS system we usually create new environment through `virtualenv` for example. Whit this approach we will have the `env` folder inside our main project and we can commit it to our github repository. Once one clone it, just activate the environment and `(env)$ pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt` in order to load all python dependencies for that project.

The problem using `virtualenv` is that it creates a `copy` from my OS python version when building a virtual environment. The point here is that, as said before, I have python 3.10.4 and I need 3.8.4 in my `env`.

In order to achieve this I installed the [pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/). It works like a [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to nodejs and I can easily switch between python versions in my OS without mess or affect my main OS.

Following the instructions in the [documentation](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#using-pyenv-to-install-python) I managed to install the version 3.8.4 in my system. In fact it installs the desired versions inside `~/.pyenv/versions` and then from there we can switch versions.

```
$ pyenv versions
system
3.8.4
3.8.4/envs/test3.8
* test3.8 (set by /home/user/Documents/vhosts/py-whatsapp-message-response-automation/.python-version)
```

In order to create a virtual environment `env` folder inside my repository would be enough to switch the python version in my operational system through `pyenv` approach and then follow the instructions to create the virtual environment using `python3 -m venv env`. I did not test this option.

Instead, I followed the steps [Using pyenv to Install Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#virtual-environments-and-pyenv) in the documentation. It works and creates kind of link between my Project Repository and the Python version inside `~/.pyenv/versions`. From here I can activate the environment and install the desired libraries.

The main problem here is that, if another user clones the repository it will not have the `env` folder in order to install the libraries to the project through `(env)$ pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt`. All the information about this repository are located out of the repository at `~/.pyenv/versions` and it can't be commited.

I would like to know how to create the `env` folder or `environment` folder inside the project using `pyenv` approach in a way that I could make it available to be commited in the version control.

Comment: Since you have gone through the steps at [RealPython](https://realpython.com/) for [virtual-environments-and-pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#virtual-environments-and-pyenv) you might like to next read through [pipenv-guide](https://realpython.com/pipenv-guide/). In general, your other users (developers, team members, interested followers) are responsible to create the environments but you can provide what they need in terms of a pipfile or a pipfile.lock to ensure they know how to set up their environment (also targeting either development or production environments as well)

Comment: after read your suggestion I applied some tests. It seems that the best option, really straightforward is to do what did not do. Change my global python to the desired version `pyenv global 3.8.4`, create my repository and environment to the version 3.8.4 `python3 -m venv env` and finally set back the global  python to the previous version `pyenv global system`.  After this process I have a repository with `3.8.4` and a system in the original version `3.10.4`